# dezor cant watch stream

Tags: package-management

```
Gtk-Message: 20:18:24.938: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
Checking for update
Update for version 1.3.2 is not available (latest version: 1.3.2, downgrade is disallowed).
checkForUpdatesAndNotify called, downloadPromise is null
[13388:0316/201829.257648:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(693)] Message 0 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost
[13388:0316/201829.257692:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(693)] Message 3 rejected by interface blink.mojom.Widget
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're trying to do. Just posting an error message will not give anyone a clue to help you.

Comment: i am trying to watch "rts.s" on livetv on kool.to with the dezor browser but it doesnt load and on windows it does work ty for fast response